# Semicolon on a function parameters

Tags: c++, c, matrix, syntax

```
matrix_* matrix_insert_values(int n; double a[][n], int m, int n)
{
    matrix_* x = matrix_new(m, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            x->v[i][j] = a[i][j];
    return x;
}
```

Example of my test matrix

```
double in[][3] = {
    { 12, -51,   4},
    {  6, 167, -68},
    { -4,  24, -41},
    { -1, 1, 0},
    { 2, 0, 3},
};
```

I'm a bit lost, I can't figure out what `int n;` is inside my argument declaration, it works over C but C++ doesn't allow this implementation. I want to understand how this is working because I'm going to migrate this code to C++.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this is not valid C.

Comment: @DietrichEpp [Really?](http://ideone.com/27g58f) (Read: standard quote please, or it didn't happen.)

Comment: Nice, never saw that before.  If I ever get a chance to do this, I am going to look like a mastermind.

Comment: @H2CO3: Looks like I was mistaken.  It is a GNU extension.  I would have sworn I saw it in the spec.

Comment: @DietrichEpp No problem, you fixed it - +1 for your answer.

Comment: I don't see how the lvalue "x->v[i][j]" can work because it implies that the member "x" is a variably modified type, which structures can't have.

Comment: @SteveEmmerson: `x` isn't a member, it's a pointer (specifically a `matrix_*`).

Comment: @MichaelBurr You're right, I should have said "the member 'v'".

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It is a seldom-used <s>feature from C99</s> GNU extension ([GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html)) that is used to forward-declare parameters used in VLA declarators.

```
matrix_* matrix_insert_values(int n; double a[][n], int m, int n);
```

Do you see how `int n` appears twice?  The first `int n;` is just a forward declaration of the actual `int n`, which is at the end.  It has to appear before `double a[][n]` because `n` is used in the declaration of `a`.  If you were okay with rearranging parameters, you could just put `n` before `a` and then you wouldn't need this feature

```
matrix_* matrix_insert_values_rearranged(int m, int n, double a[][n]);
```

### Note about C++ compatibility

To be clear, the GNU extension is just the *forward declaration* of function parameters.  The following prototype is standard C:

```
// standard C, but invalid C++
matrix_* matrix_insert_values_2(int m, int n, double a[][n]);
```

You cannot call this function from C++, because this code uses *variable length arrays,* which are not supported in C++.  You would have to rewrite the function in order to be able to call it from C++.

Comment: But as far as I can tell the `double a[][n]` won't work in C++ or at least I can not get it to work on LiveWorkSpace, although clang complains it is a C99 feature.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: That's because it's not part of C++.  C++ does not support VLAs.  C does.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: In theory, C++ does not support VLA at all.

Comment: Really? Because compiling `void foo(int n; double a[][n], int m, int n) {}` with gcc4.2 (options: `-std=c99 -pedantic -Wall`) I get: `warning: ISO C forbids forward parameter declarations` (and with clang I get tons of errors). Why does gcc say it's forbidden by ISO C?

Comment: @Cornstalks: VLAs are standard C.  Forward declaration of parameters are a GNU extension.  When you use `-pedantic` or `-std=c99` (either option), you disable most GNU extensions.

Comment: @Dietrich-epp okay, my first reading of your answer seemed to imply that rearranging the parameters would allow it to work in C++, so he will need to redesign in order to port.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Sorry, I started writing that comment before you edited to say it's a GNU extension. I was a little late on actually posting the comment, it looks like :)

Comment: I tried to put n just before a but didn't work to me, but thank now i know what i'm doing :)

Comment: It seems that to get a warning about this extension you have to specify `-pedantic`. Using just `-std=c99` doesn't cause a warning to be generated.

Comment: Even though GCC does a great job of documenting language extensions (and all in more or less one place: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html), what a pain it would be to have to find this oddball one...  I certainly would have never guessed it had something to do with VLAs.

Comment: @DietrichEpp can one like this: `matrix_* matrix_insert_values(int n=0; double a[][n], int m, int n)`?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: That makes no sense to me, I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish.  I don't know if it makes sense to the compiler.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Is it good practice to do like what?  The question is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

If that's how you call it from C always (i.e. with n and m fixed at compile time) then in C++ you can do:

```
template <int N, int M>
void matrix_insert_values(const double (&a)[M][N]);

int main() {
  double in[5][3] = {
    { 12, -51,   4},
    {  6, 167, -68},
    { -4,  24, -41},
    { -1, 1, 0},
    { 2, 0, 3},
  };

  matrix_insert_values(in);
};
```

which has N and M as template parameters and these are deduced automatically at compile time from the input passed to the function.

Comment: It won't work if the parameters are specified at runtime, which is usually when you would use a VLA to begin with.